# MySQL query to get accumulatives values

Tags: mysql

This question is related with a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159161/mysql-query-to-get-daily-differential-values). I want to get differential daily values among rows in a table that looks like here:

```
    Date           | VALUE
--------------------------------
"2011-01-14 11:00" |   2
"2011-01-14 19:30" |   5
"2011-01-15 13:30" |   7
"2011-01-15 23:50" |   6
"2011-01-16 9:30"  |   10
"2011-01-16 18:30" |   15
```

The query gets the difference/accumulative between the newest daily value and the previous newest daily value.

```
SELECT
  t1.dt AS date,
  t1.value - t2.value AS value
FROM
  (SELECT DATE(date) dt, MAX(date), VALUE as value FROM table GROUP BY dt) t1
JOIN
  (SELECT DATE(date) dt, MAX(date), VALUE as value FROM table GROUP BY dt) t2
    ON t1.dt = t2.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

So the result is something like:

```
Date               | VALUE
---------------------------
"2011-01-15 00:00" |  -1
"2011-01-16 00:00" |   6
```

But I need the accumulative value from the first day also. In general, I need the accumulative value for a day, if the previous day doesn't exist. Something like this:

```
  Date             | VALUE
---------------------------
"2011-01-14 00:00" |   3
"2011-01-15 00:00" |  -1
"2011-01-16 00:00" |   6
```

Answer (score 0):

You would almost certainly be better off processing these differences when iterating over the result set in your language of choice but the following query should work

```
SELECT
    `t1`.`date`,
    `t1`.`value`,
    IFNULL((
        SELECT CAST(`t1`.`value` AS SIGNED) - CAST(`t2`.`value` AS SIGNED)
        FROM `table` `t2`
        WHERE `t2`.`date` < `t1`.`date`
        ORDER BY `date` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ), `t1`.`value`)
FROM `table` `t1`
ORDER BY `date` ASC;
```

Comment: It doesn't result as I expected and it takes more than 2 minutes. I will try with a Java + MySQL combination

Comment: Sorry, I misread your original post. Presumably the third entry in your example output should have had a value of 5 (15 - 10). It is possible to do this in a query but it would make more sense to do it in Java (your app). The sub-selects in your sample query are unreliable. When using group by all fields in the field list should either be in the GROUP BY clause or within an aggregate function. In your queries the "VALUE" returned could be either of the values from the grouped rows.